# What does the "not an statement" error mean?

Tags: java

I am new to java programming. I tried hello world program, but I got an error "**not a statement**". Whereas when I copy, paste the hello world program from the internet, my program compiled. This is the program I used. What is meant by "**not a statement**", please explain why I got this error and what is meant by it and what should I look for when I get this error in the future. Thanks!

```
public class hello
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        System.out.println(“hello world”);
    }
}
```

My errors:-

```
hello.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                          ^
hello.java:8: error: ';' expected
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                           ^
hello.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                                         ^
hello.java:8: error: not a statement
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                                 ^
4 errors
```

Comment: Why are you using fancy quotes like `“`? Use normal ones like `"`.

Comment: If you are using macOS, disable "smart quotes"

Comment: "not a statement" is kind of meaningless in this context. The compiler just got confused because you're using characters you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You code cannot contain smart quotes like your used in your "Hello World". I replaced your smart/fancy quotes with the correct kind.

```
public class hello
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```